# Issue with styling element using ID selector

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with styling my navigation ID. I feel like I am doing everything correctly, but my HTML is not recognising my styling when I refresh it. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the HTML code -

```
<body>
    <div id="Navigation">
        <ul>
            <li> Marketing </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And here is the styling of that id -

```
#Navigation {
    width: 20%;
    height: 70%; 
    background-color: #FC0;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0 auto
}
```

Comment: What do you think doesn't work here? You haven't closed the `}` and `</div>`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Both the CSS and the HTML are enclosed properly.

Comment: your code is fine https://jsfiddle.net/12mttgvy/  Is the link to your css correct? <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your.css">

Comment: @Willox yes that is correct. I tried in chrome & safari, still nothing. Maybe its the text editor?

Comment: @Willox Possible... Because some text editors place UTF-8 BOM.

Comment: @Willox so why is everything working in the link you posted. I also tried it here https://jsbin.com/nerokabiba/edit?html,css,output and it worked fine.

Comment: @JordanMiguel Can you add `/* */` before the `#Navigation` in your CSS?

Comment: @PraveenKumar that didn't change anything. I will try to recreate the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your CSS file has a UTF-8 BOM. Try recreating the file, or add `/* */` in front of every rule. Eg:

```css
/* */
#Navigation {
  width: 20%;
  height: 70%; 
  background-color: #FC0;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: recreated the file, added /* */ in front of rule, still no progress.

Comment: I just realised, maybe I need to add my styesheet link to the head of my html?

Comment: @JordanMiguel Yes you need to.

Answer (score 4):

You are never closing your div tag.

```
<div id="Navigation"></div>
```

And make sure you have a closing curly bracket for your CSS.

```
#Navigation {
    width: 20%;
    height: 70%; 
    background-color: #FC0;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I've just edited it, still it is not working

Comment: @PraveenKumar I fixed. I stupidly didn't realise that I forgot to link the stylesheet into the html lo. Thanks for all the help dude.